# React - Getting could not proxy request even though API request posts

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, routes, mern

I'm getting this error;

> Proxy error: Could not proxy request
>   /betinfo/edit/5eb1d40c26201e00176decb0 from localhost:3000 to
>   http://localhost:5000.

But the axios posts and the edit goes through to the database.

This only happens in one of my routes.

I do have "proxy": "http://localhost:5000" in my package.json

route

```
// edit bet by specific bet id
router.route('/edit/:id').post(async (req, res) => {

try {
const { event, selection, odds, stake, bookmaker } = req.body;

const response = await Bet.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, { event, selection, odds, stake, bookmaker }, { new: false });

if (!response) return res.status(400).send("Data not found");


} catch (err) {
res.status(500).send("Something went wrong");
return;
}

});
```

action

```
export const editBet = (id, betData) => dispatch => {
 axios
     .post("/betinfo/edit/" + id, betData)
     .catch(err =>
         dispatch({
             payload: err.response.data
         })
     );
};
```

It doesn't really matter that the error comes, because it posts anyways. But when I pushed it to heroku, it's getting "Requests timeout" when this route is posted.

When I press button to post, nothing happens. But after i refresh/reload the page, then I get the proxy error.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "react": "^16.11.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.11.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.2.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: can you console.log err ?

Comment: @AtinSingh 
When I press button to post, nothing happens. But after i refresh/reload the page, then I get the proxy error, so console.log doesnt log anything

Comment: 2020-05-08T09:34:25.759298+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/betinfo/update/5eb5244dd5056d00173ac813" host="website" request_id=882e1acf-3097-4649-bc12-e10615599167 fwd="ip" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https @AtinSingh

Comment: Can you add the code where you have setup the proxy? Like package.json in your case

Comment: yes updated now @AtinSingh

Comment: sorry for the late reply. Your proxy is hardcoded to localhost. Which won't work on cloud. You need to point to a correct path.

Comment: for the proxy? do you have a suggestion which path? "/" ?

Comment: The app that you are proxying to, is it also deployed somewhere? Also, how are you serving your react build?

Comment: Deployed to Heroku. "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client" and "build": "react-scripts build",

Comment: I don't get it. This react app is different from the app that you are proxying your request to, right? First of all, You should not be proxying requests after deployment. It is mostly for development scenes. However, if you are proxying then u need to use an env variable for proxy link, and need it to point to the link where it is proxying to. You will need to settup manual proxy instead of package.json https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/#configuring-the-proxy-manually